# Who are the parents of Wonder Woman in Justice League : Gods and Monsters?

Tags: dc, justice-league-gods-and-monsters

In the movie *Justice League: Gods and Monsters* an alternate reality Justice League is shown in which the league consists of Superman, Batman, and Wonderwoman. It is shown that Wonderwoman is the granddaughter of All-Father who is a new god. I would like to know who are the parents of Wonderwoman in this reality?

Comment: I don't believe it's confirmed in this. It's Himon in the New 52; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekka